# Code that has to tell the user how many flips are needed to change B's to A's is not working correctly

Tags: python

I have written some code where I have to write a program that asks the user for a row of pancakes with them either being letter *A* or *B* where the code has to tell the user how many flips it takes to make all the pancakes *A* where the user has to input how many pancakes can be flipped at once all in a row. If the pancakes can't be flipped and be all letter *A*s the code has to output `This couldn't be done. Would you like to try again?`.

The code currently outputs the following:

```
Enter the row and the side of the pancakes A/B): BBBB
How many pancakes can flipped at one time? 2
It took 0 flips.
Would you like to run this program again?
```

where it should output the following:

```
Enter the row and the side of the pancakes (A/B): BBBB
How many pancakes can flipped at one time? 2
```

And it shouldn't tell the user if they want to play again as the pancakes haven't been fully flipped to A's.

My code is below:

```py
i = True
flips = 0

while i == True:
    pancakes = list(input('Enter the row and the side of the pancakes (A/B): '))
    flipper = int(input('How many pancakes can be flipped at one time? '))

    i = False
    if 'O' in pancakes:
        flips = flips + 1
        for x in range(flipper):
            if pancakes[x] == 'A':
                pancakes[x] = 'B'
                pancakes = (''.join(pancakes))

    if flips == 1:
        print('It took 1 flip.')
        play = input("Would you like to run this program again? ")
        if play == 'Yes' or play == 'yes' or play == 'Y' or play == 'y':
            i = True
        else:
            quit()

    if flips == 0:
        print('It took', flips, 'flip.')
        play = input("Would you like to run this program again? ")
        if play == 'Yes' or play == 'yes' or play == 'Y' or play == 'y':
            i = True
        else:
            quit()

    if flips > 1:
        print('It took', flips, 'flip.')
        play = input("Would you like to run this program again? ")
        if play == 'Yes' or play == 'yes' or play == 'Y' or play == 'y':
            i = True
        else:
            quit()
```

An issue with the code is it currently doesn't output the correct number of flips correctly.

Thanks.

Comment: You haven't implemented the flipping logic correctly - or at all, for that matter. As this seems to be some kind of homework, you'll have to show some effort there before SO users help to fix problems. There are some other obvious problems in your code though: You're mixing up pancakes (A/B) with hamburgers (T/O) pretty badly. The code uses both, the output shows something else than the code would print.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *how many pancakes can be flipped at once all in a row*... Does it mean you *have* to flip that many and they're next to each other... eg: would BAB with a value of 2 be: 1) Just flip B&B so you get AAA - so it's one flip or 2) You'd flip BA so it becomes AB, leaving you ABB, then you can flip BB together to get AAA... hence two flips required?

Comment: Hi, so for example if the user inputted BBBB and with a flip size of 2 the result would be AABB, where it can flip the pancakes that are in a row so e,g, it can't be BABA as it would've flipped the 2nd and 4th pancake. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: so just to confirm then given BBBB, the valid first flips are: AABB, BAAB, BBAA ?

Comment: Hi Jon, the aim is to get all the pancakes to be flipped up to side A. So the first step with a flipper size of 2 would be AABB and then AAAA which is a sucess and took 2 flips. If the flipper size was 3 it would be AAAB and it won't work so the code should output 'IMPOSSIBLE'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my code to solve this problem...

```py
while True:
    pancakes = input('Enter the row and the side of the pancakes (A/B): ')
    flipper = int(input('How many pancakes can be flipped at one time? '))

    result, possible = 0, True
    for row in pancakes.split('B'):
        cnt, rem = divmod(len(row), flipper)
        if rem != 0:
            possible = False
            break
        result += cnt

    if possible:
        print('It took %d flips.' % result)
        resp = input('Would you like to run this program again? ')
    else:
        resp = input("This couldn't be done. Would you like to try again? ")

    if resp.lower() not in ['yes', 'y']:
        break
```